# Regex - how to delete word that contains specific keyword

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have description in many rows, for example

```
You can see them at www.superuser.com/question/ask, but for the second opinion, you should check bowwwbowww too
```

How to delete every word that contains www, in every rows,

In this case:

1. www.superuser.com/question/ask
2. bowwwbowww

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. What regex can I use?

Comment: Do you want to keep the comma after `/ask`? What characters are you identifying as “word” character?

Comment: yes, I need to keep the comma,

Character = keyword, I mean like www, or line, or, 08232, 

so every word that contains them, deleted

Comment: OK, but `www.superuser.com/question/ask` contains more than just letters, (i.e. `.`, `/`, may be other characters) could explain what character have to be deleted? And why these ones and not the comma? And do you want to keep the space before the comma?

Comment: @Toto Sorry maybe it too complicated,
but, this is some list actually I need to delete '. / @ =' 

those letters usually typed in the URL,
(i.e. 'www.', '.com/' but sometimes without
'.' like wwwsuperusercom/question/ask), link (i.e. a=href bla bla bla),
keyword like "@myinstagramaccount", or 'hello, sunday, 0362'

About 'And why these ones and not the comma?'
the most important thing is '"' not just the comma,

Because I work in Excel/  CSV, separator between lines using '"', when I use [^ ]*www[^ ]* it will deleted,

the order of my lines (rows) in excel will be broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^ ]*www[^ ]*
```

Essentially, once detecting the "www" combination it will remove anything around it until encountering a space on either side. This includes commas, periods etc, unless you add them to the square brackets as well.
Applying the pattern to every row depends on which software is running the regex search; In np++ mentioned in the tags, it's under find -> replace -> set to regular expression, replace all.

[image: Regex]
[image: Replaced]

Comment: it's work! after use this regex, I move them to ms.excel and use =TRIM and etc (combination) to set further.

Comment: oke, it's cool, when I add "|" , I can delete other keyword like [^ ]*keywoard1|keywoard2[^ ]*

Comment: To clarify, [^ ,]www[^ ,] will stop removal at commas as well as spaces. If you wish instead to remove just the specific chars you mentioned, use eg [./@=a-zA-Z0-9]*www[./@=a-zA-Z0-9]*. I'd tinker around with the definition on regexr in your place, to get a better sense for what works in the data.